# StatusCode: 400 BadRequest using HttpClient for POST and uploading a PDF

Tags: c#, httpclient

I have a problem. I made an API on a machine that takes requests and sends them further for esigning (it has to be done like that). It works properly through Postman like this:
[image: this]

headers:
[image: headers]

but then when I try to connect a Client (in my example a default console app) I get 400 Status Code responses:

```
StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Date: Fri, 04 Mar 2022 12:48:43 GMT
  Content-Type: application/problem+json; charset=utf-8
}
```

The code that makes the call is:

```
static async void SendPDFToEsign2()
    {
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\Raul\Documents\PDFReadTest\Test.pdf");
        var participantSSN = "14812149181";

        var postContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        var fileContent = new StreamContent(new FileStream(fileInfo.FullName, FileMode.Open));
        fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/pdf");
        postContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("multipart/form-data");
        postContent.Add(fileContent, "receivedPdf");
        postContent.Add(new StringContent(participantSSN), "signerID");


        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://esign.testapp.uib.no");

        var result = client.PostAsync("/api/", postContent).Result;

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
```

I have tried a lot of solutions I found around, also with

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var fs = File.OpenRead(pathtofile))
            {
                //code to send it
            }
        }
```

but nothing seems to work in this case? If you think it matters, the API that gets called looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnoWO.png), but it works properly through postman, so I just want to recreate the postman calls through c# so I can start integrating it into the main system.

--> EDIT <--

Managed to get a 200 OK Response like this:

```
    var url = new Uri("https://esign.testapp.uib.no");
    var participantSSN = "14812149181";
    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\Raul\Documents\PDFReadTest\Test.pdf");
    using var client = new HttpClient();
    using var content = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(fileInfo.FullName));
    var postContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    postContent.Add(content, "receivedPdf", "Test.pdf");
    postContent.Add(new StringContent(participantSSN), "signerID");
    content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
    var requestUri = "/api/";
    client.BaseAddress = url;

    var result = client.PostAsync(requestUri, postContent).Result;

    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.WriteLine($"Response : {result.StatusCode}");
```

But I can't get the JSON response that I need (The one shown above in Postman picture). I can only get this:

[image: 4]

Any idea how to get that nice response that Postman gives me?

---->>> EDIT 2: FIXED <<<----
I got the right result with following code:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostPDF(System.IO.FileStream fsPDF, Participant participant)
        {
            // setup
            using var client = new HttpClient();
            var url = new Uri("https://esign.testapp.uib.no");
            using var fileContent = new StreamContent(fsPDF);
            fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
            var requestUri = "/api/";
            client.BaseAddress = url;

            // add auth token
            //var _bearerToken = "";
            //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + _bearerToken);

            // setup request data 
            MultipartFormDataContent httpContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            httpContent.Add(fileContent, "receivedPdf", "Test4.pdf"); // Hardcoded Name Test4
            httpContent.Add(new StringContent(participant.SocialSecurityNo), "signerID");

            // make the call
            var response = client.PostAsync(requestUri, httpContent);

            // return the response. perhaps save it in the DB too
            return response.Result;
        }
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: This is always wrong `using (var client = new HttpClient())` <- HttpClient, altough it has an IDispose interface should have a single static instance per application.

Comment: Does this help? https://makolyte.com/csharp-how-to-send-a-file-with-httpclient/

Comment: @JHBonarius Thanks for replying, but no it does not. Followed their code example for my case (https://i.imgur.com/E3eJ8Up.png) but I get an empty _response_

Comment: please await the response, instead of return its result

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check the last EDIT, I fixed it myself like that. Commenting this so I can mark the question as solved

Answer (score 0):

The code seems reasonable.

It looks like that API will return a 400 if the file is empty or too large. I bet you've already checked that it's not > 5MB, so my guess would be that the file isn't actually read, and you're sending 0 bytes of PDF.

Have you checked what's actually going out, by inspecting the content?

Comment: What should I check inside the content? I am not sure how the "content" of a file should look like. It currently looks like this (it has the lenghts right): https://i.imgur.com/dtOoWHR.png

Comment: it does look like there's data there. Now, I suggest you await the async Post task instead of diving into the Result. or if you must, ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult(), but a kitten will be injured.